# How to create a simple pie chart using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

Ive been trying to generate a simple pie chart using python just using two variables. representing percentages.I always encounter an error `"vcvarsall.bat"  not found` upon installing `matplotlib` package.Is it inevitable installing visual studio for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio is not required to install `matplotlib`. For best results, first install Python from python.org, either 32- or 64-bit, depending on your computer's architecture and the version of Windows you're running (for example, even if you have a 64-bit processor, if you're running 32-bit Windows, download 32-bit Python). The version doesn't especially matter, I prefer 3.3.3, but more packages are compatible with 2.7.6, so take your pick. Matplotlib and its dependencies are all available for either version.

Next, go to Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and download the following packages for your version of Python:

- [`matplotlib`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib)
- [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
- [`python-dateutil`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-dateutil)
- [`pytz`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytz)
- [`pyparsing`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyparsing)
- [`six`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#six)
- [`Pillow`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil)
- [`tornado`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tornado)
- [`pyside`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyside)
- [`pyqt`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt)

The packages are all self-extracting installers. Run them in any order, and when you're done you should be able to import and use matplotlib just fine.

An example pie chart program, from [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html):

```
from pylab import *

# make a square figure and axes
figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)

pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
                # The default startangle is 0, which would start
                # the Frogs slice on the x-axis.  With startangle=90,
                # everything is rotated counter-clockwise by 90 degrees,
                # so the plotting starts on the positive y-axis.

title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

show()
```